# Wiki API getter

Tags: python, beginner, classes

I know there are other Python wiki API classes out there. I'm writing this one because I don't need all the bells and whistles, no edits, no talks, etc. I just need to be able to search for titles and get the wiki markup.

Any advice or suggestions or comments or a review or anything really.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import re
import time
import sys
from urllib import quote_plus, _is_unicode

try:
    import json
except:
    import simplejson as json


def enum(*sequential, **named):
    enums = dict(zip(sequential, range(len(sequential))), **named)
    return type('Enum', (), enums)


class Wiki:
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        if api == None:
            self.api = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
        else:
            self.api = api
        return

    """A HTTP Request"""
    def downloadFile(self, URL=None):
        """     
        URL - The URL to fetch
        """
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        responce = opener.open(URL)
        data = responce.read()
        responce.close()
        return data.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')


    """Search the wiki for titles"""
    def search(self, searchString):
        results = []
        if (searchString != u""):
            encoded_searchString = searchString
            if isinstance(encoded_searchString, unicode):
                encoded_searchString = searchString.encode('utf-8')
            url = self.api + "?action=query&list=search&format=json&srlimit=10&srsearch=" + urllib2.quote(encoded_searchString)
            rawData = self.downloadFile(url)
            object = json.loads(rawData)

            if object:
                if 'query' in object:
                    for item in object['query']['search']:
                        wikiTitle = item['title']
                        if isinstance(wikiTitle, str):
                            wikiTitle = wikiTitle.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
                        results.append(wikiTitle)
        return results


    """Search for the top wiki title"""
    def searchTop(self, searchString):
        results = self.search(searchString)
        if len(results) > 0:
            return results[0]
        else:
            return u""


    """Get the raw markup for a title"""
    def getPage(self, title):
        # Do the best we can to get a valid wiki title
        wikiTitle = self.searchTop(title)

        if (wikiTitle != u""):
            encoded_title = wikiTitle
            if isinstance(encoded_title, unicode):
                encoded_title = title.encode('utf-8')
            url = self.api + "?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvlimit=1&titles=" + urllib2.quote(encoded_title)
            rawData = self.downloadFile(url)
            object = json.loads(rawData)

            for k, v in object['query']['pages'].items():
                if 'revisions' in v:
                    return v['revisions'][0]['*']
        return u""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Wiki:
    def __init__(self, api="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"):
        self.api = api
        return
```

This return does nothing

```
    """A HTTP Request"""
    def downloadFile(self, URL=None):
```

Python convention is to use `lowercase_with_underscores` for method names

```
        """     
        URL - The URL to fetch
        """
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

Why are you pretending to be Mozilla?

```
        responce = opener.open(URL)
```

Response is spelled wrong

```
        data = responce.read()
        responce.close()
        return data.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
```

This whole function should probably be a free function, not a method.

```
    """Search the wiki for titles"""
    def search(self, searchString):
```

Parameters by convention should be named `lowercase_with_underscore`

```
        results = []
        if (searchString != u""):
```

No need for the `(` and `)`. Also you can just do: `if searchString:`

```
            encoded_searchString = searchString
```

Why?

```
            if isinstance(encoded_searchString, unicode):
                encoded_searchString = searchString.encode('utf-8')
            url = self.api + "?action=query&list=search&format=json&srlimit=10&srsearch=" + urllib2.quote(encoded_searchString)
            rawData = self.downloadFile(url)
            object = json.loads(rawData)
```

I'd combine these two lines

```
            if object:
```

In what circumstance will this be false? If that happens you should probably do something besides pretend that nothing happened.

```
                if 'query' in object:
                    for item in object['query']['search']:
                        wikiTitle = item['title']
                        if isinstance(wikiTitle, str):
                            wikiTitle = wikiTitle.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
                        results.append(wikiTitle)
        return results


    """Search for the top wiki title"""
    def searchTop(self, searchString):
        results = self.search(searchString)
        if len(results) > 0:
            return results[0]
        else:
            return u""
```

Do you really want an empty string if your result wasn't found? You should probably throw an exception here. Returning an empty string will just make failures hard to trace.

```
    """Get the raw markup for a title"""
    def getPage(self, title):
        # Do the best we can to get a valid wiki title
        wikiTitle = self.searchTop(title)

        if (wikiTitle != u""):
            encoded_title = wikiTitle
            if isinstance(encoded_title, unicode):
                encoded_title = title.encode('utf-8')
            url = self.api + "?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvlimit=1&titles=" + urllib2.quote(encoded_title)
            rawData = self.downloadFile(url)
            object = json.loads(rawData)

            for k, v in object['query']['pages'].items():
                if 'revisions' in v:
                    return v['revisions'][0]['*']
        return u""
```

Don't default to stupid defaults. If you can't get the requested page throw an error with as much detail as possible, don't just throw me an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious one that jumps out at me is this:

```
class Wiki:
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        if api == None:
            self.api = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
        else:
            self.api = api
        return
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
class Wiki:
    def __init__(self, api="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"):
        self.api = api
```